# Make does not execute a recipe for a "phony" file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***I have a makefile, like:***

```make
# Force Make, to do a "directory-search" (via VPATH), for the non-existent file 'all'
$(shell rm -rf 'all')
# If 'D' is a "regular" file, we remove it first.
$(shell rm -rf 'D')
# 'D' is a VPATH-directory
$(shell mkdir 'D')
# File 'all' gets vpath-ized to 'D/all'
$(shell touch 'D/all')



VPATH = D

root : all
    echo 'prerequisite is: "$<"'

all :
    echo '$@'


.PHONY: D/all
```

***Executing, I get:***

```console
echo 'prerequisite is: "D/all"'
prerequisite is: "D/all"
```

Looking closely, it is clear, that:

1. `D/all` is a `phony` target. Right?
2. `all` was vpath-ized into `D/all` (As evident by the output above, for the target `all`).

So, given all that, how is it that Make will not honor a `.PHONY : D/all` directive, and ***not*** execute its recipe, at all?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are supposed to call the phony target 'all' and not 'D/all'.

Just a hunch, try to put the phony statement right above the all target.

Im not near a computer to check it out, so hopefully it will work...